# Install New Relic using SaltStack on Windows Minion

Tags: windows, saltstack

How can I install New Relic on my Windows minions via SaltStack without having to RDP into each Windows minion?

I found some [New Relic documentation](http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/windows-server-monitoring/server-monitor-installation-windows) for installing via the command-line on Windows, but would it be possible to use the Windows-based Salt package manager for this, without resorting to `cmd.run`?

I tried using this against salt-minion v0.17.5-52, but the minions don't return anything:

```
salt '*' cmd.run "msiexec /i 'C:/Install/New Relic/newrelic.msi'
/L*v install.log NR_LICENSE_KEY='<my licence key>'" -v
```